# MongoDB aggregation group by field colapsing several cases into the same group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to solve the following case with MongoDB aggregation framework. Documents in my `entities` collection hasve

- a `_id.type` field which can be `""`, `null` or a non-empty string, and
- a `attr` field which is a string.

I want to group by `_id.type` but elements in `""` and `null` must belong to the same group. I'm trying with this stage in the aggregation pipeline:

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {"$cond": [{"$in": ["$_id.type", [null, ""]]}, "", "$_id.type"]},
        "attrNames": {
            "$addToSet": "$attrName"
        }
    }
},
```

My understanding is that `_id` defines the key for the group so what I'm trying to achive is

- If the `_id.type` is `null` or `""` then 2nd element in `$cond` array is used so key is `""` (so putting these two particular cases in the same group)
- In any other case, them 3rd element in the `$cond` array is used so key is `_id.type`

However I get the following error message:

> A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

so I guess I'm doing something bad.

How should I modify my aggregation statement (or use a new one) to solve this case, please?

Comment: Could you show how you use this `$group` ? It seems like you just need to pass an array of stages to `aggregate` and you're passing pipeline stages as separate arguments

Comment: Ensure that each pipeline stage is an element within an array like `db.yourCollection.aggregate([{$group: {...}}])` and that each pipelines stage object is formatted correctly such that the stage operator (e.g. `$group`) is the only top-level field. If for example you have `{$group: {...}, someOtherField: 'some value'}`, then you're going to encounter an error. Please show us the entire aggregation call if you continue to encounter problems as we can only speculate as to what the problem might be without seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments (thanks!) it happens I used incorrectly the aggregation syntax. Using the following statement has worked:

```
> db.entities.aggregate({
    "$group": {
        "_id": {"$cond": [{"$in": ["$_id.type", [null, ""]]}, "", "$_id.type"]},
        "attrNames": {
            "$addToSet": "$attrName"
        }
    }
})
```